# Override object property using prototype

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to override `.name` property of constructor b. But it is not working. Whats wrong with code.

```
function b(){
    this.name="johnson"
}

b.prototype.name="david"
var a= new b()

alert(a.name)
```

Comment: Why voting down. Did I post something wrong

Comment: Well, saying "it is not working" without saying either what you expect or what you get is a bit of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're seeing `"johnson"` in your `alert`, then it's working exactly correctly.

When you add a property to an object directly, it takes precedence over any property with the same name on its prototype. So in

```
var a = new b();
```

...even though `a`'s prototype has `name="david"`, `a` *itself* has `name="johnson"` (assigned within the call to `b`), and so that wins.

Reading the value of an object property basically works like this (assume `__proto__` is a magic property of an object that refers to its prototype [which it will be, in ES6]):

```
function getPropertyValue(obj, propertyName) {

    // Start with the object itself
    var o = obj;

    // Loop until we find an object in the prototype chain that has a property called "name"
    while (!o.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
        // This one doesn't, look to its prototype
        o = o.__proto__;

        // Did it have one?
        if (!o) {
            // No, property not found
            return undefined;
        }
    }
    return o[propertyName];
}
```